# Boilerplate Service Worker Create React App ("undefined is not a function")

Tags: javascript, service-worker, create-react-app, sentry

Started getting an error in sentry from boilerplate create react code:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'e.unregister()')
```

I have not changed anything with service workers and the error is coming from here:

```
export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Any idea if I can ignore this error or what I should be doing to fix it?  I haven't experienced it myself, only see it in the sentry error logs with over 10 users at this point.

Comment: Hey Stephen, could you provide more information, if possible a [mcve] or just more of the boilerplate you're referencing?

Comment: So a minimal reproducible example is simply the create react app referenced here- ```https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app``` - nothing has been changed inside this file- serviceWorker.js and index.js contains  the same - ```serviceWorker.unregister();``` (I am not using service workers)

Answer (score 0):

Following is a default serviceWorker.js file generated with `create-react-app` please use this and try if this works.
Also check for differences if any to make you understand the error occurred!

```js
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.


const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
  // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
  window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
  // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
  window.location.hostname.match(
    /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
  )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
     
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service '
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                'tabs for this page are closed.'
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using the default/ I have changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

See how it's called on this src code?

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template-typescript/template/src/index.tsx

That's the pre-compiled version of index.js. It seems your minified version of index.js (minified because the import has been renamed `e` as in `e`.unregister())

That unregister function is the default and means you did not register for any service worker. The issue is the code on the client side, maybe see if the users had anything in common like a browser version.

Comment: Interesting.  So it is all windows (7, 8.1, 10) and 100% chrome but many different versions of chrome.  Not really sure why just windows or how to fix this though

Comment: Windows is probably your users' most common OS and Chrome is the most common browser. Windows also indicates that this is (probably) on desktop/laptop computers, which should have a stable internet connection. Try using Google Analytics to evaluate if that's a fair sampling of your users, in which case I'd say it's probably just circumstantial and not worth chasing. Hotjar is a cool tool to see what a user experiences on your site. Other than that, it's going to take some deep digging and it's probably not going to be solved on SO.

Comment: Thanks.  Mac is the most common, but definitely chrome.  Already use all, unfortunately haven't seen anything in Hotjar yet